# What are the costs of a Mechanic's services?

Tags: pricing, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

In an Fantasy Flight Games Star Wars RPG Campaign:

For various reasons I want to pay a random NPC mechanic to perform an attachment modification check on my weapon instead of my character doing it himself. Assuming I supplied all materials and supplies, what would be a expected base cost for his services (assume Core World legal establishment ~Rebellion era)?

This comes up because my GM has a GM-PC droid which I "own". He forces me to pay said droid any time I want him to do anything (including mechanics checks). This is sometimes way overpriced for mundane things like this, which is fine because I can just find another mechanic somewhere on a world somewhere. The mechanic will then charge me an even more ridiculous amount with no negotiation forcing me to use "my" droid. I need proof of correct base amounts to show my GM to clarify what the mechanic should be paid, regardless of what the droid demands.

Comment: Maybe you should become a mechanic, it seems like a profitable career.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Not official, but this might be useful: https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/87293-proposed-service-costs/#entry824500

Comment: Note that the link I supplied references that some things, such as starship repairs, which are apparently covered in the books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.  Mechanic costs are not listed for most things, but if you want a RAW reference, the book Operational Costs p 12 lists prices for hourly maintenance costs for repairs at different star ports.

> Grade 1 Imperial Class Star Port - 23-30 cr/hour
>
> Grade 2 Stellar Class Star Port - 30 cr/hour
>
> Grade 3 Standard Class Star Port - 40 cr/hour
>
> Grade 4 Limited Services Star Port - 20-50 cr/hour
>
> Grade 5 Landing Field - variable cr/hour

I hope this helps you in your quest for a better weapon.  However if you are doing clandestine missions, I suggest you leave your improved weapon on your ship.  I have had too many stolen from me, it's often better to take one off a downed storm trooper.

My most recent favorite was a DR-45 Dragoon Cavalry Blaster w Bantha Eye sight, Blaster actuating module and a Custom Grip w all mods: +3 Dam = 11 dam, 3 crit, +2 Accurate, Auto Adv, +2 Pierce.

But my all time favorite were my Paired Nova Vipers for my Gunslinger (one black and one silver) Nicknamed "Fury and Finesse" w all the above mods. Finesse would connect if Fury hit with advantages.

Hope you find the right droid.  May the Force be With You!